# Where can I get free words list for my word games?

Tags: word-game, reference-request

I'm making word games. Where can I find free word lists (English, French and German) that are free to use, even for commercial purposes?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [`words`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)). It's a list of English words. Free to use, even for commercial purposes. The license can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kevina/wordlist/master/scowl/Copyright). It begins:

> The collective work is Copyright 2000-2016 by Kevin Atkinson as well as any of the copyrights mentioned below:
>
> Copyright 2000-2016 by Kevin Atkinson
>
> Permission to use, copy, modify, distribute and sell these word lists, the associated scripts, the output created from the scripts, and its documentation for any purpose is hereby granted without fee, provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies and that both that copyright notice and this permission notice appear in supporting documentation.

`sudo apt install wamerican` (wor wyour wpreferred wdialect) will place this file in `/usr/share/dict/words` on Ubuntu. Depending on how restrictive you want your dictionary to be, you might want to consider other similar packages; `wamerican-small` contains fewer words, and on the other end `wamerican-insane` might provide a Words-with-Friends-like experience.

There's also a `wfrench` package that installs a French wordlist to `/usr/share/dict/french`. `wngerman` installs a German list to `/usr/share/dict/wngerman`; if you want the pre-spelling-reform version, use `wogerman` instead. You'll have to do some poking around yourself to make sure you can use these for commercial purposes, but I expect you'll be pleased.

`sudo apt install wordlist` will show you a list of such packages. There are quite a few languages available beyond these three.